# problem on portrait mode of a WebView based application

Tags: android, android-webview, device-orientation

I have a Android web application for Tab by using WebView. My everything is developed on server side by using asp.net.
the application design is quite ok on landscape mode but its break on portrait mode.

What should I do now, design every page for portrait mode or something.

Comment: "its break" is not very descriptive of your problem, is it now?

Answer (score 1):

just add   android:screenOrientation="portrait" to the activity (in ur case in webview activity)in the AndroidManifest.xml.   For example:

```
    <activity android:name=".SomeActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

or programmaticaly

setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);     //  Fixed Portrait orientation

dolet me know it works or not

Comment: i think its not about orientation problem. Its Design related problem. like for application we design any activity for landscape we added layout-land folder and .xml for landscape. I wanted to know what for this on WebView application ??

Comment: the activity where you are loading the url  , go that activity in android.menifestfile and set the  orienation as  mentioned above , the orientation will be set and it will be same for all webpages which  you will be acessing  until you are in that  activity

Comment: Thanks , but you are talking about fixed orientation , i don't want it.i want it for both orientation. when i change the orientation that time its reload its url and breaking the UI.

Comment: @ar  i hope    this link will surely work for you   to handle your problem  ,do let me know it is  solved or not    http://www.gitshah.com/search/label/how%20to%20handle%20screen%20orientation%20changes

Comment: Thanks, i have already fixed this issues, may be i couldn't able to clear the issues... my issues was with UI related..what should i do in server side? in device size orientation problem can be done, but my design is based on landscape.